# How to encode the string in to "windows-1252" using ios?

Tags: ios, type-conversion, windows-1252

The following string is working perfectly in android,please give me suggestion for encoding this  in ios.

Android Example:String s = "hhh"; 
                s.getBytes("Windows-1252");

Comment: Why do you want to use Windows-1252?  UTF-8 is a more compatible encoding across technology stacks.

Comment: using windows-1252 because all mobile applications using same format.                                                           Example:Room 408 Prime Tower, No.22, Chaowai Street,
Chaoyang District, Beijing , P.R. China 100020

中国北京市朝阳区朝外大街22号泛利大厦408室

Comment: You mean "*all (your) mobile applications*" are using the same format?  Because I'm not sure I agree that all or even most mobile apps use Windows-1252.

Comment: yes William,In the above mentioned Chinese format we need show the data in mobile app.in our web application(website) we are showing in this format so we need show the same in mobile app.

Comment: Okay, but the Windows-1252 code page doesn't contain any Chinese characters and is closer to ASCII.  I think that might pose a problem for you.  Good luck!

Comment: william any alternative way is there for converting unicode in ios

Comment: Thank you yar for kind support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look at the docs for `NSString` would give you:

```
NSString *s = @"hhh";
NSData *data = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
uint_8 *bytes = [data bytes];
```

Comment: Hi rmaddy,thank you very much for sharing information i am trying same code ios but it is working.please see the below example:Database saving string :

Room 408 Prime Tower, No.22, Chaowai Street,
Chaoyang District, Beijing , P.R. China 100020

ä¸­å›½åŒ—äº¬å¸‚æœé˜³åŒºæœå¤–å¤§è¡—22å·æ³›åˆ©å¤§åŽ¦408å®¤
Exact Output of the string :

Room 408 Prime Tower, No.22, Chaowai Street,
Chaoyang District, Beijing , P.R. China 100020

中国北京市朝阳区朝外大街22号泛利大厦408室

Comment: Hi rmaddy,issue is resolve its working fine.thank you very much for sharing information.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent code in iOS looks like this

```
NSString *str = @"hhh";
char buffer[100];
[str getCString:buffer maxLength:100 encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
```